# How can I set a group of previously saved cookies in a Chrome Extension by using chrome.cookies.set()?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies, google-chrome-extension, session-cookies

I'm trying to create a very simple Chrome extension to emulate Firefox containers and have a different session on each group of tabs. Right now, I'm focusing on cookies but I can't figure out how the chrome.cookies.set() works. I want my extension to detect when the user switches to a tab marked as another session's tab, save all previous session's cookies into a dictionary, delete all the browser cookies and then set all the browser cookies to all current session's cookies saved into the dictionary. The saving + removing all cookies works but I just can't do the setting part. Maybe you just can't set cookies manually this way this and you have to use something else. Also, I think my manifest.json file is fine, since I have the cookies, active tab, and <all_urls> permissions

```
function handleActivated(activeInfo) {
    console.log("Tab " + activeInfo.tabId +
        " was activated. From: " + getSession(activeInfo.tabId));
    if (getSession(activeInfo.tabId) !== currentActiveSession) {
        lastActiveSession = currentActiveSession;
        currentActiveSession = getSession(activeInfo.tabId);
        console.log("last session: " + lastActiveSession + " | current session: " + currentActiveSession);

        //SWAPS COOKIES
        chrome.cookies.getAll({}, (cookies) => {
            sessionDictionary[lastActiveSession]["cookieStore"] = cookies;
            for (let removedCookie of cookies) {
                let urlString = "https://" +  removedCookie.domain;
                chrome.cookies.remove({ url: urlString, name: removedCookie.name });
            }
            for(let cookie of sessionDictionary[currentActiveSession]["cookieStore"]) {
                let c = {
                    domain : cookie.domain,
                    expirationDate: cookie.expirationDate,
                    httpOnly: cookie.httpOnly,
                    name: cookie.name,
                    path: cookie.path,
                    sameSite: cookie.sameSite,
                    secure: cookie.secure,
                    storeId: cookie.storeId,
                    url: "https://" + cookie.domain,
                    value: cookie.value
                }        
                chrome.cookies.set(c);
            }
        }); 
    }
}
```

I'm not sure about the url property in the cookie I want to set. Also, I cannot set the hostOnly property so I just manually removed it.